# error android studio sdk facebook

Tags: android-studio

se me presenta el siguiente error en android studio al tratar de integrar el sdk de android studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo:

import com.android.build.OutputFile

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.platzimusic"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: Dentro de tu archivo strings.xml agrega la entrada: <string name="facebook_app_id"> VALOR API KEY </string> conteniendo el valor del APU Key de facebook, agregué repuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@string/facebook_app_id`  indica un valor dentro del archivo `strings.xml` que es ubicado dentro de `/res/values/`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dentro de este archivo debes agregar una entrada conteniendo el valor de tu API Key, por ejemplo:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id"> VALOR API KEY </string>
```

de esta forma el metadato tomara el valor que necesitas y funcionará sin problemas el proyecto.

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```